# wider space for case equations

Tags: cases

I am trying to write lots of simultaneous equations. But as you can see from the image, inserting one space and two spaces both look ugly.

[image: result]

This is the code I use to generate these two equations

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\textbf{22} Solve the following simultaneous equations\\
\hspace*{5mm}\textbf{a} $\begin{cases}\dfrac{4}{x}-\dfrac{3}{y}=1\\\dfrac{8}{x}+\dfrac{9}{y}=7\\\end{cases}\quad
$\\\\\\
\hspace*{5mm}\textbf{b} $\begin{cases}\dfrac{9}{x}+\dfrac{8}{y}=-1\\\\\dfrac{12}{x}-\dfrac{6}{y}=7\\\end{cases}\quad
$
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to halve the gap?

It's just that I have to write hundreds of these and I am really keen to find out how.

Thanks :)

Comment: You can use the syntax `\\[10pt]` for example, to specify the extra gap you want added, and tailor this to your desired spacing.

Comment: Try `dcases` instead of `cases`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dcases` (provided by `mathtools`).

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\textbf{22} Solve the following simultaneous equations
\[
\textbf{a }
\begin{dcases}
\frac{4}{x}-\frac{3}{y}=1\\
\frac{8}{x}+\frac{9}{y}=7
\end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]